# Join with Subquery table in Django ORM

Tags: django-orm

Suppose I have a model named *Book* and another named *Reaction* that has a foreign key to *Book* and a string field named `outcome`. There are a large number of book and reaction rows in the database. I want to make a query to database using Django ORM that yields the following SQL:

```
SELECT b.*, r.n_like, r.n_dislike
FROM book b
JOIN (
  SELECT
    book_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN outcome='like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) n_like,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN outcome='dislike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) n_dislike
  FROM reaction
  GROUP BY book_id) r ON b.id=r.book_id;
```

How can I do that?

Please notice that this query returns only books with at least one reaction and their corresponding number of *like* and *dislike* reactions.

I know how to use `Case`, `When`, `Sum` and `Coalesce` in Django. I also know how to write a query that generates those annotations within the `SELECT` clause (I tried this kind of query and it is very slow). My question merely is about joining and selecting a subquery with a Django model. The subquery is something like this:

```
reactions_query = Subquery(
  Reaction.objects
  .values('book_id')
  .annotate(n_like=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(outcome='like', then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())), 0))
  .annotate(n_dislike=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(outcome='dislike', then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())), 0))
  .values('book_id', 'n_like', 'n_dislike')
)

Book.objects.filter(...) <-- how?
```

**EDIT**: These are not my actual models. I simplified them. Anyway, this is how they look like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField()
    
class Reaction(models.Model):
    LIKE = 'like'
    DISLIKE = 'dislike'
    OUTCOME_CHOICES = ((LIKE, ':)'), (DISLIKE, ':('))

    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=OUTCOME_OPTIONS, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added them to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Book.objects.filter(
    reaction__isnull=False
).annotate(
    n_like=Coalesce(Count('reaction', filter=Q(outcome='like')), Value(0)),
    n_dislike=Coalesce(Count('reaction', filter=Q(outcome='dislike')), Value(0))
)
```

The `.filter(reaction__isnull=False)` will prevent including `Book`s without any reaction. This will thus create a query with an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I tried this query. I does not generate the query I described in the question. It generates TWO subqueries in the SELECT clause that I believe is slow.

Comment: @melmi: the query is not verbatim the one in your question, but one that is semantically equivalent. Using two `SELECT`s with an extra `GROUP BY` would result in a lot of duplicate work.